# Combo-box items related to another combo-box item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

I have two combo-box:
*startYear* will list 10 years from this year backwards "2016, 2015. 2014, ...". 
*endYear* Should list 10 afterwards the year chosen in *startYear* combo-box.
Here's my code but it is not working, it won't even show a bug or crash just won't build.
Note: i put the whole code for the combo-box in a method because I'll use it later on a bigger project.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int YearDropMenuItems()
    {
            int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int[] items1 = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                items1[i] = year - i;
                startYearComboBox.Items.Add(items1[i]);
            }
            if (startYearComboBox.SelectedItem == null)
            {
            endYearComboBox.Items.Add(year);
            int year2 = (int)startYearComboBox.SelectedItem;
            int[] items2 = new int[10];
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                items2[j] = year2 + 1;
                endYearComboBox.Items.Add(items2[j]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int year2 = (int)startYearComboBox.SelectedItem;
            int[] items2 = new int[10];
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                items2[j] = year2 + 1;
                endYearComboBox.Items.Add(items2[j]);
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        YearDropMenuItems();  

    }
}
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred. The debugger related that error to the line 'int year2 = (int)startYearComboBox.SelectedItem;'

Comment: And yes, i want it to run one the form is created, just to let the user choose  a year

Comment: By adding the if null block, i meant for the program to wait for the user to chose a year from the 'startYear' combo-box

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked by dealing with the _SelectedIndexChanged Event_  posted here for if some one else was having the same problem